# Delete expired tokens in oauth2-server-php

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I'm using the bshaffer/oauth2-server-php module to authenticate my rest api. Everything works fine but meanwhile I have over 20,000 access tokens in the database.
As I read, the framework will not delete expired tokens automatically or by config parameter. So I'm trying to do the job by my own.
I know the tables which hold the tokens and I already built the delete statements. But I can't find the right place (the right class/method) to hook with my cleanup routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good option here is to create a Command, here a small part in Symfony but can also be a plain PHP command since you know the table names and just execute it every hour:

```
    $doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
    $entityManager = $doctrine->getEntityManager();

    $qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('t')
        ->from('OAuth2ServerBundle:AccessToken', 't')
        ->where('t.expires < :now')
        ->setParameter('now', new \DateTime(), Type::DATETIME);
    $accessTokens = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    $cleanedTokens = 0;
    foreach ($accessTokens as $token) {
        $entityManager->remove($token);
        $cleanedTokens++;
    }
```

This just covers the access_token table as an example. By the way I still could not get how to change the Token expiration with this library ;)

UPDATE: To change the lifetimes just edit parameters.yml and add

```
    oauth2.server.config:
       auth_code_lifetime: 30
       access_lifetime: 120
       refresh_token_lifetime: 432000
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read the complete source off bshaffer oauth server. 
 
But want you can try is to create your own class by extending from class Server. 
And use the __destruct() function to be executed when the object customServer is destroyed by PHP

```
<?php
include('src/OAuth2/Server.php'); # make sure the path is correct.

class customServer extends Server {

  public __construct(($storage = array(), array $config = array(), array $grantTypes = array(), array $responseTypes = array(), TokenTypeInterface $tokenType = null, ScopeInterface $scopeUtil = null, ClientAssertionTypeInterface $clientAssertionType = null)) {  
    parent::_construct($storage, $config, $grantTypes, $responseTypes, $tokenType, $scopeUtil, $clientAssertionType);
  }
}

public function __destruct() {
  // run your cleanup SQL from here.
}
```

?>

Comment: The idea is really good but in my case I'm using zend-mvc-auth for the authentication process so I don't know if it's possible to extend the Server class at any time.